# ASP.net Web API POST/PUT request don't execute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a weird situation. When I start my web api and try to consume it through a web page or fiddler...it doesn't post/put for initial few requests.
Doesn't give any error.

After a few tries it starts working properly.

I tried to debug by putting breakpoint on method in controller.

After clicking on submit button on web page initial 2-3 times, the page accepts the request but breakpoint never gets hit.

After trying 2-3 times it starts working properly.

Is there any pre-initialization or anything needs to be take care..?

Pls note all get requests are working fine.

Any idea..what can I do.?

Comment: did you try putting debug point on your client side?

Comment: hard to know without seeing the code you use to make the request, or any debugging info. Debug on the client-side as mentioned. Your browser has very powerful tools which can give you big clues about what's going on.